# V8: ES6 proxies don't support iteration protocol when targeting custom objects?

Tags: javascript, proxy, ecmascript-6, v8

I'm using the V8 API to create JavaScript objects. Some of these objects support iteration by setting up a native (intercepted) function at the `Symbol.iterator` property.

Iterating such an object via [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) works perfectly. However, if I wrap it in a null proxy (e.g., `let x = new Proxy(obj, {});`), the resulting object is *not* iterable and throws a `TypeError` with the message "Illegal invocation" if an attempt is made to iterate over it.

Wrapping a standard array doesn't exhibit this issue. Is this a V8 bug?

Comment: What would you expect to iterate over if you've wrapped it in a null proxy ?

Comment: @Pogrindis I'd expect the proxy to iterate over its target; that's what happens if the target is a standard array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Wrapping a standard array doesn't exhibit this issue.

Yes, that's how [array iterators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-iterator-objects) work. They don't care about the kind of the object they are iterating - they simply access its `.length` and indexed properties (which are routed normally through the proxy).

However, other standard exotic objects don't behave that nice either. If you try to invoke `[Symbol​.iterator]()` on a [typed array](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%typedarray%.prototype.values), [map](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createmapiterator) or [set](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createsetiterator) that is wrapped in a proxy, they'll bitch about being invoked on the wrong object.

> Is this a V8 bug?

No, it's a bug in the application. You've got three choices:

- Create an iterator that does not depend on the internal slots of your custom objects, but rather uses their public (proxy-interceptable) property interface. Make sure your `[Symbol.iterator]` method does not typecheck its receiver.
- Check the type of the receiver in your iterator method, and if it is a proxy (i.e. has a `[[ProxyTarget]]` internal slot) then use that value. I would strongly advise against this, as it does not match the standard behaviour and breaches the proxy when bypassing the handler.
- Don't use a null proxy:

  ```
  let x = new Proxy(obj, {
      get(target, key, receiver) {
         if (key === Symbol.iterator)
             return target[Symbol.iterator].bind(target);
         else
             return Reflect.get(target, key, receiver);
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Bergi. You're right; the problem is that my `[Symbol.iterator]` method expects its holder to have certain private fields, which aren't accessible when the holder is a proxy. Quick follow-up question: Do you know why `proxy[Symbol.iterator]()` throws an exception without invoking my interceptor, whereas `it = proxy[Symbol.iterator]; it();` invokes the interceptor and crashes as expected?

Comment: Both of those should invoke the `get` handler if that is what you mean by "interceptor"? I can't imagine why it would not.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to clarify. I'm not specifying a custom `get` handler; the method is stored as a normal property on the target and appears to be retrieved correctly in both cases. What I don't understand is why the first syntax throws an exception without calling the method, while the second syntax calls the method and crashes as expected. The method itself is a native function whose invocation causes a callback into native (C++) code, but that should be irrelevant AFAICT.

Comment: The obvious difference is the receiver (`proxy` vs `undefined`), which would be the value of the `this` keyword in a js function, but I have no idea how native functions are affected by it. Apparently there's some guard that prevents your custom function from running, but I don't know about V8 details. Does it happen on non-proxy objects as well?

Comment: Right again; the difference appears to be somewhere deep within V8's function-call machinery. It looks like `x.call(y)` fails early if `x` is a native function and `y` is a proxy.